# What would be a sutibal local "update" server?

Tags: networking, apt, server, updates

What would be the simplest and a minimalistic way for network with around 20 Ubuntu 20.04 Servers to download the packages not from http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu rather from a local "update" server? Update management and other things are not needed, the local update server shall just provide the packages. Currently I am thinking about apt-mirror or a proxy server. I don't want to install the ubuntu update server.

I would be happy for recommendations and links for installation documentations :)

Comment: Alternative: use puppetmaster (and yes I realize it does not meet your requirements ;-)). The master will use the regular repo and the puppets get it from the master. Totally worth it to invest some time in it. Minimalistic... no... Simplest? Maybe not but it is very well documented how to set this up. Example setup/config: https://medium.com/@vikumkbv/how-to-install-puppet-master-and-puppet-agent-in-linux-system-e4afa6eb0ef  Most of it is copy-paste.

Comment: Thanks for the information.